# Java 8 cannot import java.util.function

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to import the package java.util.function 
but I keep getting the following error:

```
FP.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
import java.util.function;
                ^
  symbol:   class function
  location: package java.util
```

I have verified that I am using jdk 1.8.0_11 (using javac -version).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That isn't how you import a package, this

```
import java.util.function;
```

should be

```
import java.util.function.*;
```

To import the classes in the [`java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: Ah, that was really silly of me. Can't believe I wasted so much time on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
import java.util.function.Function;
```

`Function` is a class under `java.util.function` package.

Answer (score 2):

for importing all classes in  package you have to use *

like

```
import x.y.*;
```

for importing only one class you should use class name like

```
import x.y.z;
```

for your case as [function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) is a package so you should use

```
import java.util.function.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Intellij, 
Go to Files > Settings > Build,Execution, Deployment > Compiiler > Java Compiler.
In this, change the Target Bytecode version to 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue while executing my project. As I had Java 15 on my machine , I changed targeted Bytecode version to 15 and it worked.
Go to Files > Settings > Build,Execution, Deployment > Compiiler > Java Compiler. In this, change the Target Bytecode version to 15